# matlab ja builder failed with mex file

Tags: java, matlab, mex, matlab-deployment

I am working on an optimization problem by using the matlab BONMIN solver (http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/index.php/Probs/MINLP), which is a third-party optimization toolbox. I worked out a matlab program involving the invocation of the BONMIN solver. In my case, I need to package this program into Java pakcage, thus, I choose to use **matlab ja builder** to do so. However, I got the following error message:

***The file
'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonminCplex.mexw64'
appears to be a MEX-file. It shadows the MATLAB file
'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonminCplex.m'
but will not execute properly at runtime, as it does not export a function named 'mexFunction.'***

My matlab version is 2012b. Is there anyone who have any idea about this problem?

Thanks!

======================================

```
ant:

<mkdir dir="F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\fudan.se.graphmatching.optimization\distrib" />
<mkdir dir="F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\fudan.se.graphmatching.optimization\src" />
mcc -W 'java:fudan.se.graphmatching.optimization,OptimalGraphMatcher' -T link:lib -d F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\fudan.se.graphmatching.optimization\src -w enable:specified_file_mismatch -w enable:repeated_file -w enable:switch_ignored -w enable:missing_lib_sentinel -w enable:demo_license -v 'class{OptimalGraphMatcher:F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\apply_funcs.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\check_validity.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\compute_optimization.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\constraints.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\function_matrix_multiply.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\generate_relation.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\generate_simulated_constraint.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\obj_function.m,F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\transfer_from_vv_to_ve.m}'
Compiler version: 4.18 (R2012b)
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\matlab\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\spcuilib\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\optim\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\optimlib\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\globaloptim\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\signal\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\ident\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\general\mcc.enc
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\control\mcc.enc
mcc.enc file not found for licensed toolbox file C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\simrf\simrfmasks\cleanup.p
All files in directory C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\simrf\simrfmasks will be excluded.
Processing C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\mcc.enc
Processing include files...
2 item(s) added.
Processing directories installed with MCR...
The file F:\Documents\MATLAB\Optimization\fudan.se.graphmatching.optimization\src\mccExcludedFiles.log contains a list of functions excluded from the CTF archive.
0 item(s) added.
Generating MATLAB path for the compiled application...
Created 112 path items.
Begin validation of MEX files: Fri Jan 17 14:07:40 2014
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\@distcomp\dctCmdWindowSize.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\cluster\+parallel\+internal\+cluster\workerShutdown.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\dct_psfcns.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\distcompByteBuffer2MxArray.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\distcompMakeByteBufferHandle.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\distcompMxArray2ByteBuffer.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\distcompdeserialize.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\distcompserialize.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\getUncPathFromMappedDrive.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\distcomp\pct_unsetenvmex.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\private\dctPathAndClearNotification.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\distcomp\private\dctRegisterMpiFunctions.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\ident\nlident\@linear\soevaluate.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\ident\nlident\@wavenet\soevaluate.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\optim\optim\+internal\+optim\constrImpliedBoundaries.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\optim\optim\+internal\+optim\getNNZcounts.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\optim\optim\private\activesetqp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\optim\optim\private\barrierConvexQPmex.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\HamEig.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\HamGenEig.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\bdschur.mexw64'.
Found MATLAB file 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\bdschur.m'.
MEX file
'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\bdschur.mexw64'
is valid. It contains 'mexFunction.'
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\ddaeresp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\ddaesim.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\frdelay.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\frkernel.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\hlyapslv.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\lyapslv.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\matscale.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\mimozero.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\normrank.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\quadgp1.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\quadgp2.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\rrqrf.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\ssfresp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\ssresp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\sssim.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\sylvslv.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\tfresp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\tfsim.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\triperm.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\zpkboderesp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\zpkfresp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\zpkresp.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\shared\controllib\engine\numerics\zpksim.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\signal\signal\buffer.mexw64'.
Found MATLAB file 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\signal\signal\buffer.m'.
MEX file
'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\signal\signal\buffer.mexw64'
is valid. It contains 'mexFunction.'
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\signal\signal\private\upfirdnmex.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\DNToMatrix.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\MatrixToDN.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\computeDN.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\convertToDouble.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\matrixBitXor.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\sobolIndexed.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\sobolNet.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\sobolPoint.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012b\toolbox\stats\stats\@sobolset\private\sobolSequence.mexw64'.
No conflicting MATLAB file found.
Validating 'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonmin.mexw64'.
Found MATLAB file 'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonmin.m'.
MEX file
'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonmin.mexw64'
is valid. It contains 'mexFunction.'
Validating 'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonminCplex.mexw64'.
Found MATLAB file 'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonminCplex.m'.
End validation of MEX files: Fri Jan 17 14:07:40 2014
The file
'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonminCplex.mexw64'
appears to be a MEX-file. It shadows the MATLAB file
'F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\Solvers\bonmin\bonminCplex.m'
but will not execute properly at runtime, as it does not export a function named 'mexFunction.'
```

Comment: The error message complains that the mex-file does not seem to be a proper mex-function. Are you sure that in your matlab-environment you're really calling bonminCplex.mexw64 instead of the builtin?

Comment: Hi @sebastian, the files under the directory "F:\Documents\MATLAB\OPTI Toolbox\" are all the third-party library I invoke from my own matlab program. I think that the matlab ja builder automatically analyzes the dependencies and find those files when building java package. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Generally not I think. As you can read from the output e.g. `bonmin.mexw64` is checked by matlab and is found ok. There seems to be something wrong with `bonminCplex.mexw64` however.

Comment: Hi, @sebastian, thanks a lot for your reply. However, I can run it well in matlab command line. Theoretically, a correct matlab program should be compiled smoothly by matlab ja builder. :(

Comment: @YunLin: As the error says, something is wrong with the MEX-file. If you have the C/C++ source code of the MEX-function, try to compile it again. To check if it is a proper MEX-file, use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and verify that it correctly exports the `mexFunction` entry method.

Comment: Hi @Amro, Thanks. Your explanation makes sense. The final solution is to delete the "bonminCplex.mexw64". And now, it works fine.